Fitting copula and simulating from it in R
Let’s say we have log returns of three assets: APPLE, NETFLIX and GOOGLE and I want to optimise my investment portfolio. In order to do this I can create mathematical programming problem on top of it. Apart from the details, I need to simulate (using R and copula package) more data based on historical log returns of these three assets in order to have better optimization - for example 1000 observations of each of the assets (1000 for APPLE, 1000 for NETFLIX, 1000 for GOOGLE) instead of, say, 32 historical returns for each of them.
As far as I’m concerned to do this I need to:

Choose copula type to fit it to the data (either arbitrarily or through VineCopulas)
Fit parameters of the copula using the matrix of pseudo-observations of the assets using fitCopula
Choose marginal distribution functions for every asset log returns
Use mvdc to connect copula to the marginal distributions
Apply rmvdc to these obtained copula to get simulated data

My problem is that I want to use EMPIRICAL MARGINAL DISTRIBUTIONS, instead of choosing some function like Gauss or t-Student, to generate data from t-Student Copula coupled with these marginal distributions. Why there is no option in mvdc function to input EMPIRICAL distributions? I’m confused - maybe I don’t understand parts of theory leading to it? Thanks for the explanation in advance.

Maybe you should ask the creators of the R package? I do not think it is theoretically impossible to use empirical marginal distributions, just that the authors chose not to implement that option.
